# How to upgrade containerd on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, containerd, kata-containers

I'm trying to run Kata Container 2.4.3 on my own machine. However, Kata Containers 2.4.3 is compatible with contaienrd v1.5.2 while I'm using containerd v1.2.10. Is there any solution to upgrade containerd on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Have you tried https://containerd.io/downloads/#installing-binaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually download and install containerd 1.5.5 from Ubuntu 18.04 in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/containerd/containerd_1.5.5-0ubuntu3~18.04.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./containerd_1.5.5-0ubuntu3~18.04.2_amd64.deb
```

If you get in trouble when trying to update End of Life Ubuntu 16.04 because it is an old, unsupported release, read the answers to [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/). The repositories for older Ubuntu releases that are not supported get moved to an archive server. These repositories are available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can use containerd v1.5.2 now!